# Angularjs - select : ng-change - new value not selected

Tags: angularjs

I have a select tag with ng-change.
When **ng-change** is triggered the new value is not selected (in **calibreChanged** function, **$scope.sell.stock** has the same value as before selecting a new one).
Am I wrong somewhere?
It looks like binding is not effective here.

```
<select ng-model="sell.stock.id"  class="col-md-5" ng-change="calibreChanged()"
     ng-options="currentStock.id as currentStock.calibre for currentStock in stocks">
</select>

$scope.calibreChanged = function(){
    var stock = $scope.sell.stock;
}
```

Comment: where did you check your value ?

Comment: breakpoint in calibreChanged function

Comment: working fine here : https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/rymbp5ak/

Comment: @user1260928 I think everything is ok, but it looks like `ng-change` function is called before `ng-model` sends new value to the model.